# How do I get a list of games that are discounted during whole Steam Sale?

Tags: steam

On the main Stream store page I can see daily deals (current and from past day), community choice deals and flash sales. I've noted however, that some games are on sale discounted until the end of Steam Sale (Summer sale at time of writing this question). Right now they're annotated with "SUMMER SALE! Offer ends 30 June". How can I get a list of these games?

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[This website](http://steamdb.info/sales) has a list of every Steam sale currently active, with the biggest savings at the top of the page. Keep an eye on those flash deals!

Screenshot:

[image]

Happy spending!